# Dynamically create nested s4 class slot names and assign values in R

Tags: r, r-s4, slots

I try to assign values to nested s4 classes slots in R in a dynamic way. What I have so far is the code below. I create the following nested classes ending with nested slot of type numeric.

```
setClass('slot', slots = c(slot = 'numeric'))
setClass('object', slots = c(slot = 'slot'))
object = new('object')
object@slot@slot
```

Typical assignement works as expected:

```
object@slot@slot = 1
```

or:

```
slot(object@slot, "slot") <- 1
```

What I want do to however is a dynamic creation of the slot names for 
the assignment for example with paste from a vector like e.g.

```
slot_path = c("object", "slot", "slot")
```

Using eval and parse does the trick to convert the string into the object  and shows me the object or in that case here the slot of the object.

```
eval(parse(text = paste(slot_path, collapse="@")))
```

However assigning values to that kind of construct seems not to work as expected.

```
eval(parse(text = paste(slot_path, collapse="@"))) <- 2
```

Gives me the error that says:

> Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection.

If I paste the path manually like that:

```
eval(parse(text = "object@slot@slot")) <- 1
```

I get the error that says:

> Error in eval(parse(text = "object@slot@slot")) <- 1 :    target of
>   assignment expands to non-language object

Trying to assign with the `assign()` function also does not do the trick.
The call below:

```
assign(x = slot(eval(parse(text = "object@slot")), "slot"), value = 1)
```

Gives me the error:

> Error in assign(x = slot(eval(parse(text = "object@slot")), "slot"),
>   value = 1) : invalid first argument

Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: slot has an assignment method, is that what you want? `?methods::\`slot<-\``

Comment: Nope that is not working: Error in slot(eval(parse(text = "object@slot")), "slot") <- "test" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

Comment: That is why I was using the assign function as this should handle assignment of values to to complex strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

For numeric:

```
eval(parse(text = eval(expression(paste(pasted_slot_path, "<-", value)))))
```

For character:

```
value = sprintf('"%s"',value)
    eval(parse(text = eval(expression(paste(pasted_slot_path, "<-", value)))))
```

Comment: This is a cool solution, but it causes all objects to be evaluated as vectors, thus it cannot be used where `value` is another object (i.e. S4 in my case)